# Given two functions $\phi(k)$ and $E(k)$, how can I determine the functional relationship $\phi(E)$?

Tags: calculus, functions

If I have two functions $\phi(k)$ and $E(k)$ expressed explicitly as (complicated) functions of $k,$ obtained using computer algebra software. I have reason to suspect that $\phi$ could be written purely as a function of $E,$ that is, $\phi(E),$ but *not* $\phi(E(k),k).$ Is there a way to test if such a functional relation exists, given the information I have? If such a relation exists, how might I go about finding the functional form of $\phi(E)$? Is there a general procedure?

I have done some exploration using the chain rule. For example, I can study the function $$\frac{d\phi}{dE}=\frac{\frac{d\phi}{dk}}{\frac{dE}{dk}},$$

(which will be expressed as a function of $k$) and any higher order derivatives I like. However, what I really want is $\phi(E)$. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect it might be possible $\phi(E,k)$, if you use "reverse" substitution on $\phi$. If ordinary substitution goes from $E(k)$ to the $E$ expression, we need reverse, i.e. going from the expression to the $E(k)$.  Basically you need to find a pattern from $\phi$ that looks like $E$, and then write $\phi$ as expression containing $E$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi=f(k)$ and $E=g(k).$ You want to eliminate $k$ between these two equations so that $\phi$ is a single-valued function of $E.$ If $g$ is injective, then we have that $g^{-1}(E)=k,$ so that $$\phi=f(g^{-1}(E)),$$ the desired relationship. Whether this is single-valued depends on the definition of $f,$ which you do not tell us.

Assuming smoothness, you can easily tell in what range of values of $k$ the function $g$ is injective by examining the signs of the derivative $g'.$ It is injective whenever it has constant sign.